# Why is there information loss here?

Tags: functions, computer-science

I posted this a while ago, but realized that actually this works, but produces information loss. Here is the process:

Let's try to reduce a number $x$. We will be using base $\beta$ for this process.

Let $x$ be our "worst case" number.

$$
x_{10} = ((\beta-1)\sum_{n=0}^k \beta^n)_{10}
$$

Next thing we will do is take the number written in base $\beta$. Therefore:

$$
x_{10} = (\beta\beta..\beta)_{\beta}
$$

Now we take the number in base beta and take the values literally, transforming them to the numeration system of base 10.

$$
y_{10} = ((\beta-1)\sum_{n=0}^k 10^n)_{10}
$$

The magic trick here, but where my main mistake may be, is that:

$$
x_{10} > y_{10} \iff ((\beta-1)\sum_{n=0}^k \beta^n)_{10} > ((\beta-1)\sum_{n=0}^k 10^n)_{10}
$$

And we finally get:

$$
x_{10} > y_{10} \\ 
\iff \\ 
(\sum_{n=0}^k \beta^n)_{10} > (\sum_{n=0}^k 10^n)_{10} \\
\iff \\
\beta > 10
$$

If this process is repeated I find that this iterative function is not bijective, which basically makes the whole reduction thing a loss of time. Why is this just injective?

Thanks.

Comment: Your use of $\sum$ seems to be really strange -- it looks like you're trying to use it as a notation for strings of digits or something?

Comment: What's the meaning of the digit $\beta$ in a base-$\beta$ expansion?

Comment: @SilvioLevy $\beta$ in base-$\beta$ is $10$ in said base.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It is literally the sum. Where are the confusing parts so can I fix them?